# how can i resolve the default apache page for django with apache

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

im new at deploying and i've been trying to deploy my django app and i can only seem to get the default :`"it works"` page to work. i have followed a few tutorials to no luck. 
my `'/etc/apache2/sites-available/37.***.22.**'` Virtual host:

```
 `<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@37.***.22.**
            ServerName 37.***.22.**
            DocumentRoot /var/www/37.***.22.**/public_html
            <Directory />
                    Options FollowSymLinks
                    AllowOverride None
            </Directory>
            <Directory /var/www/37.***.22.**/public_html>
                    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                    AllowOverride None
                    Order allow,deny


 allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn CustomLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

WSGI file:

```
import os
import sys
import site

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('~/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('~/MyProject/django-bookmarks')
sys.path.append('~/MyProject/django-bookmarks/django_bookmarks')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_bookmarks.settings'

# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("~/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv/bin/activate_this.$
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

i had SCP'ed my files for my djagno app into the MyProject dir on the server.
i also ran the `a2ensite 37.***.22.25` and restarted apache, but even with that i still get the "it works" default page. how can i resolve this?
i had also installed Postfgress. i really want to deploy this app asap and have been struggling, and learning alot also at the same time! any advise would be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't see how this could work at all. You don't have anything that sets up mod_wsgi or references your wsgi script. If you're seeing a Django page, it must be because of some other configuration.

Comment: i do not see a django page, it's only the default apache page. how would i set references to my wsgi script or set up mod_wsgi? im very new at this

Comment: Have you read and followed the perfectly good deployment instructions on the Django documentation site?

Comment: yes, i gave myself time to read them just to avoid the confusion with other tutorials i found. i followed them so it works, partially. my app runs when i go to http://myIp/django-bookmarks. my problem now is that i can move to various pages of my app by typing, e.g. myIP/django-bookmarks/login or myIP/django-bookmarks/register.....however, when i click on the tabs in the itself, it takes me to myIP/register (without the 'django-bookmarks') and then says "URL not found on this server". trying to find out where i messed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have [mod_wsgi](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) installed and enabled for Apache.

You will also want to ensure that you have defined both WSGIProcessGroup and WSGIScriptAlias ([configuration directives](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives) for mod_wsgi) for the virtual host.

Comment: mod_wsgi is installed. i followed the instructions here :https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts                                                             .i got everything to work as per the instructions there, but i cant seem to understand how i can get my app up and running.

Comment: The blog article you linked to only discusses setting up virtual hosts for Apache. If we assume Apache is configured properly to this point, the next step is to get mod_wsgi (allows Apache and Django to "talk" to each other) configured for your virtual host.  Review how to use WSGIProcessGroup and WSGIScriptAlias...those are both missing from your virtual host configuration in your original post.

Comment: thanks, i gave myself time and went through the django deployment instructions and have added the WSGIScriptAlias and WSGIProcessGroup and my app works partially for now. though im having some problems with the URLs.i can move to various pages of my app by typing, e.g. myIP/django-bookmarks/login or myIP/django-bookmarks/register.....however, when i click on the tabs in the itself, it takes me to myIP/register (without the 'django-bookmarks') and then says "URL not found on this server". trying to find out where i messed up

Comment: If this solved your initial problem, then go ahead and check this off as the correct answer.  Then, if you continue to have problems related to a new issue, open up a new question if you want additional support.

Comment: I had the same problem. I did all steps correctly but browser was showing default apache index.html page. I just reload the page using Ctl + Shift + R in chrome , and it worked. It was showing apache default index.html page from cache.